# Cannot assign COM port to HC-05 bluetooth device

Tags: serial, bluetooth, arduino-nano, communication, hc-05

I can't set a COM port to my paired BT module. For better understanding [I recorded a YouTube video](http://youtu.be/vu9cK6emnIo) to make sure I show everything.

Hardware:

- Arduino Nano knock-off by [RobotDyn](http://robotdyn.com) (atmega168)
- Bluetooth module HC-05 (zs-040) which looks [like this](https://cdn.instructables.com/FLP/2YI3/HX6ARQKC/FLP2YI3HX6ARQKC.MEDIUM.jpg)
- Windows 10 Home 64 bit on tablet

I have wired them up like this [image].

However, before that, I tried to wire it up without the resistors (so I hope I didn't damage anything).

Here is my very simple code which should just echo back what it get.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println(Serial.parseInt());
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, can you add details about your Windows? what version is it? and version of bluetooth adapter

Comment: @dpw I have Windows 10 Home 64 bit. It's a tablet and the BT adapter for the tablet is build in so I don't know any additional information about it.

Comment: I have exact the same problem.
Expect also to see a com port number after my device a MLT-B05 (clone of HC-05) is paired and (after fill in correct pass-code) is connected.
Did you see a you tube film for a correct assignment of the com port? I did everything the same as you did, but perhaps we are both wrong. Harry

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, there is nothing wrong (yet) on the Arduino. You can check  [this](http://www.technorms.com/46164/bluetooth-guide-windows-10) or [this](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-20605/). Unlike previous windows version, Win 10 tend to "ignore" bluetooth connection, so you have to assign the COM port manually.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. However when I want to assign the COM port I have no device to choose from even though I can see it paired in the main BT window.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOC45.png) Here is screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Ah, the same problem also occur to me. I don't know if there are any solution other than mine, which solved by using external bluetooth dongle. Turns out my build-in bluetooth adapter is not compatible with the bluetooth module (which is HC-05 and HC-06).

Comment: Well but my mobile phone also cannot communicate with the module. It seems to me pretty odd that the built-in BT cannot communicate with other BT devices.